# Do I need to recompile a C-mruby application after making chnages in mruby script file?

Tags: c, compilation, mruby

I have a C application. The  C application needs a few script files containing *mruby* code. Is it possible to run this application using current *mruby* implementation without recompilation (after I make any change in mruby scripts) ?   If yes how ?

But I did not find any such method adress [here](http://mruby.org/docs/articles/executing-ruby-code-with-mruby.html). If in a  C application (where mruby is embedded) I have to recompile entire application, then what is the advantage of *mruby* ?

My idea of scripting languages is that if I change any thing in the *mruby* script file , no recompilation of the entire application will be required, and this will increase productivity.

I consider  this as an advantage of using any script file in a native application.

Kindly help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in any scenario, script, or file that uses mruby code you don't need to recompile your program.

Comment: This site has a review mechanism: some posts are identified as potentially needing a closer look. You have posted an answer to an old question, which qualifies it as a "Late answer", and I found it that way. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15203912. That said, I edited it to make it clearer, but I haven't voted on it because I have no idea whether the answer is correct or not, as I know nothing about mruby.